# Can you turn in a mix of bones?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I am working towards getting the [Temple Key](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Temple_key) and the main task requires you to offer 100 bones to the sacred bone burner. The wiki says that it has to be 100 "babydragon bones, dragon bones, lava dragon bones or superior dragon bones" but it does not say if I can hand in a mix. Im doing this for Twisted League points and its annoying to only be able to focus on 1 type of dragon. It would go faster if I could turn in 2 types of bones.

So as the title says, can I turn in mix of bones to the sacred bone burner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main game I used a few dragon bones at first and then all baby dragon bones after since they are cheaper, and it worked for me. You should be able to mix them.

The [page for the burner](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_Bone_Burner) itself words it as "eligible bones" which makes it sound like a combination is fine:

> ...they must offer 100 eligible types of bones (babydragon bones, dragon bones, lava dragon bones, or superior dragon bones) to the bone burner...